Не срабатывает useEffect при обновлении компонента
Сломал уже всю голову, буду рад любым подсказкам. Есть корзина с индикатором(когда в корзине что-то есть - он горит, нету - не горит).
Вот функция добавления товаров в корзину, она находится у родителя, а результат прокидывается в саму корзину пропсами.
const addItem = (item, e) => {
const elem = basketItem.find(i => i.name === item.name);
if (elem) {
  elem.quantity += e;
} else {
  basketItem.push({ ...item, quantity: 1 });
}
setBasketItem([ ...basketItem ]);

}
Вот код корзины
function Basket(props) {  



const toggle = () => setIsOpen(!isOpen);

  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const [sum, setSum] = useState(0);
  const [countItem, setCountItem] = useState(false);

  const checkout = () => {
    alert('Ваш заказ был успешно оформлен, ожидайте доставку! Мы знаем где вы живёте ;)')
  }


  useEffect(() => {
    if (props.basketItem.length > 0) {
      setCountItem(true);
    } else {
      setCountItem(false);
    }  
  })


  let counterClass = countItem ? "counter" : "none"

  function renderItems(arr) {
    
const items =  arr.map((item, i) => {

  if(item.quantity == 0) {
    arr.slice(i, 1);
  } else {
    return ( 
      <div 
          key={i}>
              <Row>
                <Col sm="12">
                  <Card body
                  className="inline">
                    <CardTitle tag="h5"
                    className="lh">
                      {item.name} | Количество: {item.quantity} <br />
                      Цена: {item.price}
                    </CardTitle>
                    <Button color="success"
                    size="sm"
                    className="size"
                    onClick={() => props.addItem(item, 1)}
                    >
                      +1
                    </Button>
                    <Button color="danger"
                    size="sm"
                    className="size"
                    onClick={() => props.addItem(item, -1)}
                    >
                      -1
                    </Button>
                  </Card>
                </Col>
              </Row>
      </div>
  )
  }
    
    
});

return (
    <>
        {items}
    </>
)
}

  const itemsDone = renderItems(props.basketItem)
  
  

  return (
    <>
        <div>
          <img src={basket} className="basket" onClick={toggle} />
          <div className={counterClass}></div>
        </div>
        <Offcanvas toggle={toggle} 
        isOpen={isOpen}
        direction="end"
        scrollable>
          <OffcanvasHeader toggle={toggle}>
            Корзина
          </OffcanvasHeader>
          <OffcanvasBody>
            {itemsDone}
          </OffcanvasBody>
          <h5>Сумма товаров в корзине: {sum}</h5>
          <Button className="checkout"
            color="primary"
            onClick={checkout}>
            Оформить заказ
            </Button>
        </Offcanvas>
    </>
  );
}

Дело в том, что при добавлении товара в корзину, индикатор загорается(добавляется класс counter), но если все товары из корзины удалены, то индикатор так и остается гореть, не тухнет. Не понимаю, как так? В пропсах же приходит пустой массив, карточка с товаром пропадает из корзины, значит компонент перересовывается, но при этом индикатор никуда не уходит. Пробовал в useEffect ставить разные зависимости, от пропсов в том числе, но ничего не помогает.

а класс в разметке меняется?

useEffect не имеет зависимостей. Он выполнится либо 1 раз, либо зациклится и упадет с ошибкой. Если эффект не реагировал на смену зависимостей, то возможно это объект, который передается по ссылке, поэтому изменения не видны(если ссылка не менялась). Нужен более подробный код, что бы понимать, какие данные передаются в Basket(props) и как это происходит

@SwaD Да, передается действительно объект, точнее даже массив объектов, через функцию addItem, но ведь в самой функции стоит setBasketItem([ ...basketItem ]), чтобы менялось состояние и ссылка. Товары в корзине добавляются\убираются корректно, но вот индикатор таким же способом работать не хочет. Подскажите, какой код дополнить чтобы стало понятнее?

Как минимум, что бы можно было связать ваш basketItem  с тем компонентом, где он используется. Сейчас пример с обновлением состояния(setBasketItem([ ...basketItem ])) оторван от остального кода
